# Doubt Regarding Notation with Exponents.

Tags: notation, exponentiation

Consider $a^{b^c}$ without any brackets. My question is, if the brackets are not mentioned, what is the convention regarding the position of the brackets?

Comment: Usually it is $a^{(b^c)}$

Comment: power towers are the first step for huge numbers, they are always calculated from "above" (or from the "right", if we write the expression in a row). This way we get much much larger numbers than with other conventions. Most software tools also interprete it this way. If we mean $(a^b)^c$ , we better write it either this way or just $a^{bc}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention is that $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$. I believe this convention was chosen because the other bracketing, $(a^b)^c$, can easily be written as $a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter's comments are right; $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}$. This is an unsurprising convention if we look at the MathJax needed to say it, `a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}`.